# Burning OGG compressed file to CD with Brasero

Tags: soundconverter

I converted about 3 GB of flac audio to about 165 MB  of very low ogg format. However, when I want to burn it to a 700MB CD, it told me that I exceeded my limit by 3 GB.

I checked the folder and its contents it showed the audio files as 165 MB ogg format.
 But, still it registers on my burner as over exceeding my minute limit.

I am using k3b and brasero, and yet another burner xfburn.  I used  "sound converter" to convert the audio files.   Yet every burner reports that I,m over exceeding my
minute limit.

I don't get it.  I can only assume that the converter is the problem and that the new audio info isn't being read by the burners.   Reading in fact what it was and not what it is...

Comment: I've edited your question to have a propper formatting. Please have a look at the preview first next time. Also try to reread your question for correct grammar / spelling next time (at least as good as possible; I know that not everyone can write in English without errors - me neither).
An approach to answer your question: Have you burned an "audio cd" or just dragged and dropped the files? In case of an  audio cd, the files will most likely be converted to a special audio cd format again... Give a link to the conversion tool also, so we have more information. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you edit your post without the extra spaces. The extra spaces are used for formatting, and as it your post is extremely hard to read.

Comment: To add to mozzbozz: In the case of an audio CD, the audio data needs to be stored uncompressed, which would return it to its original size of ~3 GB.

Answer (score 1):

As mozzbozz said, your burning program obviously creates a standard audio cd to playback on every cd player. Therefore all audio files are converted into cd audio format. You ever heard of cd quality as reference for good audio quality in comparison with compressed formats like mp3? All standard audio cds have 44,1kHz sampling rate and 16bit stereo, no matter what the source had.

So you have to burn something like an mp3 cd, but this can not be read by old players. Or you have to burn at least 4-5 standard audio cds, but then you can have excellent quality and play it on every device. (Use the uncompressed source files then!)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Did you read my last sentence?

Comment: Apparently not. sorry!